# How to calculate the index (lexicographical order) when the combination is given

Tags: algorithm, performance, math, combinatorics

I know that there is an algorithm that permits, given a combination of number (no repetitions, no order), calculates the index of the lexicographic order.
It would be very useful for my application to speedup things...

For example:

```
combination(10, 5)  
1 - 1 2 3 4 5  
2 - 1 2 3 4 6  
3 - 1 2 3 4 7  
....  
251 - 5 7 8 9 10  
252 - 6 7 8 9 10
```

I need that the algorithm returns the index of the given combination.
es: `index( 2, 5, 7, 8, 10 )` --> index

EDIT: actually I'm using a java application that generates all combinations C(53, 5) and inserts them into a TreeMap.
My idea is to create an array that contains all combinations (and related data) that I can index with this algorithm.
Everything is to speedup combination searching.
However I tried some (not all) of your solutions and the algorithms that you proposed are slower that a get() from TreeMap.
If it helps: my needs are for a combination of 5 from 53 starting from 0 to 52.

Thank you again to all :-)

Comment: I take it from your example that what needs to be indexed is a list `m` entries taken from a set of `n` known elements? Is a lookup table feasible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a snippet that will do the work.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const int n = 10;
    const int k = 5;

    int combination[k] = {2, 5, 7, 8, 10};

    int index = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i != k; ++i)
    {
        for (++j; j != combination[i]; ++j)
        {
            index += c(n - j, k - i - 1);
        }
    }

    std::cout << index + 1 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It assumes you have a function

```
int c(int n, int k);
```

that will return the number of combinations of choosing k elements out of n elements.
The loop calculates the number of combinations preceding the given combination.
By adding one at the end we get the actual index.

For the given combination there are
c(9, 4) = 126 combinations containing 1 and hence preceding it in lexicographic order.

Of the combinations containing 2 as the smallest number there are

c(7, 3) = 35 combinations having 3 as the second smallest number

c(6, 3) = 20 combinations having 4 as the second smallest number

All of these are preceding the given combination.

Of the combinations containing 2 and 5 as the two smallest numbers there are

c(4, 2) = 6 combinations having 6 as the third smallest number.

All of these are preceding the given combination.

Etc.

If you put a print statement in the inner loop you will get the numbers
126, 35, 20, 6, 1.
Hope that explains the code.

Comment: I tried this solution, but it's slower than using a TreeMap. With TreeMap my application goes at 1,2 seconds/iteration, instead, with this algorithm, it goes at 16 seconds/iteration.

Comment: The only thing in the inner loop is the call to c(n, k). I would be suspicious of the implementation of that function.

Comment: public static int getCombsNumber(int N, int K)
    {
        int combinationsNumber=1;
        for( int i=0; i<K; i++) combinationsNumber*=N-i;
        for( int i=2; i<=K; i++) combinationsNumber/=i;
        return combinationsNumber;
    }

Comment: The best thing to do is cache the c(n,k) values.

Comment: Ha, I've almost the same algorithm as yours in [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455634/find-the-index-of-a-given-combination-of-natural-numbers-among-those-returned/39551493#39551493) answer (in Python) :)

Answer (score 6):

Convert your number selections to a [factorial base number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system#Permutations). This number will be the index you want. Technically this calculates the lexicographical index of all permutations, but if you only give it combinations, the indexes will still be well ordered, just with some large gaps for all the permutations that come in between each combination.

Edit: pseudocode removed, it was incorrect, but the method above should work. Too tired to come up with correct pseudocode at the moment.

Edit 2: Here's an example. Say we were choosing a combination of 5 elements from a set of 10 elements, like in your example above. If the combination was `2 3 4 6 8`, you would get the related factorial base number like so:

Take the unselected elements and count how many you have to pass by to get to the one you are selecting.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
2 -> 1
1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
3 -> 1
1 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
4 -> 1
1 5 6 7 8 9 10
6 -> 2
1 5 7 8 9 10
8 -> 3
```

So the index in factorial base is `1112300000`

In decimal base, it's

`1*9! + 1*8! + 1*7! + 2*6! + 3*5! = 410040`

Comment: an example would be fantastic :-)

Comment: It does not need to give all permutations but all combinations for any given k in other words the sum(n choose k) for k=1...n = 2^n - so merely a 10 bit vector would be 2^10 or 1024 possible values for bits representing any number of the set turned on or off.  So using a base factorial is not only more complicated to implement but inefficient in algorithmic and space complexity.  Recommend MSN answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is Algorithm 2.7 **kSubsetLexRank** on page 44 of *Combinatorial Algorithms* by Kreher and Stinson.

```
r = 0
t[0] = 0
for i from 1 to k
    if t[i - 1] + 1 <= t[i] - 1
        for j from t[i - 1] to t[i] - 1
            r = r + choose(n - j, k - i)
return r
```

The array t holds your values, for example [5 7 8 9 10].  The function choose(n, k) calculates the number "n choose k".  The result value r will be the index, 251 for the example.  Other inputs are n and k, for the example they would be 10 and 5.

Comment: The code snippet here is wrong as it sets t[0]=0 but the correct code can be found: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/53976/versions/5/previews/kSubsetLexRank.m/index.html

Answer (score 2):

zero-base,

```
# v: array of length k consisting of numbers between 0 and n-1 (ascending)
def index_of_combination(n,k,v):
    idx = 0
    for p in range(k-1):
        if p == 0: arrg = range(1,v[p]+1)
        else: arrg = range(v[p-1]+2, v[p]+1)
        for a in arrg:
            idx += combi[n-a, k-1-p]
    idx += v[k-1] - v[k-2] - 1
    return idx
```

Answer (score 1):

Null Set has the right approach. The index corresponds to the factorial-base number of the sequence. You build a factorial-base number just like any other base number, except that the base decreases for each digit.

Now, the value of each digit in the factorial-base number is the number of elements less than it that have not yet been used. So, for combination(10, 5):

```
(1 2 3 4 5) == 0*9!/5! + 0*8!/5! + 0*7!/5! + 0*6!/5! + 0*5!/5!
            == 0*3024 + 0*336 + 0*42 + 0*6 + 0*1
            == 0

(10 9 8 7 6) == 9*3024 + 8*336 + 7*42 + 6*6 + 5*1
             == 30239
```

It should be pretty easy to calculate the index incrementally.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a set of positive integers 0<=x_1 < x_2< ... < x_k , then you could use something called the squashed order:

```
I = sum(j=1..k) Choose(x_j,j)
```

The beauty of the squashed order is that it works independent of the largest value in the parent set.

The squashed order is not the order you are looking for, but it is related.

To use the squashed order to get the lexicographic order in the set of k-subsets of {1,...,n) is by taking

```
1 <= x1 < ... < x_k <=n
```

compute

```
 0 <= n-x_k < n-x_(k-1) ... < n-x_1
```

Then compute the squashed order index of (n-x_k,...,n-k_1)

Then subtract the squashed order index from Choose(n,k) to get your result, which is the lexicographic index.

If you have relatively small values of n and k, you can cache all the values Choose(a,b) with a

See  [Anderson, Combinatorics on Finite Sets, pp 112-119](http://books.google.com/books?id=RjDd4RaqrIwC&lpg=PA140&ots=tj5RAYOy_e&dq=squashed%20order&pg=PA112#v=onepage&q=squashed%20order&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

There's another way to do all this. You could generate all possible combinations and write them into a binary file where each comb is represented by it's index starting from zero. Then, when you need to find an index, and the combination is given, you apply a binary search on the file. Here's the function. It's written in VB.NET 2010 for my lotto program, it works with Israel lottery system so there's a bonus (7th) number; just ignore it.

```
Public Function Comb2Index( _
ByVal gAr() As Byte) As UInt32
 Dim mxPntr As UInt32 = WHL.AMT.WHL_SYS_00     '(16.273.488)
 Dim mdPntr As UInt32 = mxPntr \ 2
 Dim eqCntr As Byte
 Dim rdAr() As Byte

    modBinary.OpenFile(WHL.WHL_SYS_00, _
    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

    Do
    modBinary.ReadBlock(mdPntr, rdAr)
RP: If eqCntr = 7 Then GoTo EX

        If gAr(eqCntr) = rdAr(eqCntr) Then
           eqCntr += 1
           GoTo RP

        ElseIf gAr(eqCntr) < rdAr(eqCntr) Then
            If eqCntr > 0 Then eqCntr = 0
               mxPntr = mdPntr
               mdPntr \= 2

        ElseIf gAr(eqCntr) > rdAr(eqCntr) Then
            If eqCntr > 0 Then eqCntr = 0
            mdPntr += (mxPntr - mdPntr) \ 2
        End If

    Loop Until eqCntr = 7

EX: modBinary.CloseFile()
    Return mdPntr

End Function
```

P.S. It takes 5 to 10 mins to generate 16 million combs on a Core 2 Duo. To find the index using binary search on file takes 397 milliseconds on a SATA drive.

Answer (score 1):

I needed also the same for a project of mine and the fastest solution I found was (Python):

```
import math

def nCr(n,r):
    f = math.factorial
    return f(n) / f(r) / f(n-r)

def index(comb,n,k):
    r=nCr(n,k)
    for i in range(k):
        if n-comb[i]<k-i:continue
        r=r-nCr(n-comb[i],k-i)
    return r
```

My input "comb" contained elements in increasing order You can test the code with for example:

```
import itertools
k=3
t=[1,2,3,4,5]
for x in itertools.combinations(t, k):
    print x,index(x,len(t),k)
```

It is not hard to prove that if comb=(a1,a2,a3...,ak) (in increasing order) then:

index=[nCk-(n-a1+1)Ck]  +  [(n-a1)C(k-1)-(n-a2+1)C(k-1)]   +  ... =
    nCk -(n-a1)Ck -(n-a2)C(k-1) - .... -(n-ak)C1

Comment: Best answer imo

Comment: Note that in Python 3, math.comb(n, k) does n choose k so you dont need the nCr function

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Never mind. This is completely wrong.

---

Let your combination be (a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, ..., a<sub>k-1</sub>, a<sub>k</sub>) where a<sub>1</sub> < a<sub>2</sub> < ... < a<sub>k</sub>. Let choose(a,b) = a!/(b!*(a-b)!) if a >= b and 0 otherwise. Then, the index you are looking for is

> choose(a<sub>k</sub>-1, k) + choose(a<sub>k-1</sub>-1, k-1) + choose(a<sub>k-2</sub>-1, k-2) + ... + choose (a<sub>2</sub>-1, 2) + choose (a<sub>1</sub>-1, 1) + 1

The first term counts the number of k-element combinations such that the largest element is less than a<sub>k</sub>. The second term counts the number of (k-1)-element combinations such that the largest element is less than a<sub>k-1</sub>. And, so on.

Notice that the size of the universe of elements to be chosen from (10 in your example) does not play a role in the computation of the index. Can you see why?

Comment: This does not give the lexicographic ordering. For example, `combination(5,3)` has (1,2,5) in position 3, but this formula gives 5.

Comment: You're right. This is completely wrong. I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the maximum setSize is not too large, you can simply generate a lookup table, where the inputs are encoded this way:

```
  int index(a,b,c,...)
  {
      int key = 0;
      key |= 1<<a;
      key |= 1<<b;
      key |= 1<<c;
      //repeat for all arguments
      return Lookup[key];
  }
```

To generate the lookup table, look at [this "banker's order" algorithm](http://applied-math.org/subset.pdf).  Generate all the combinations, and also store the base index for each nItems.  *(For the example on p6, this would be [0,1,5,11,15]).*  Note that by you storing the answers in the opposite order from the example (LSBs set first)  you will only need one table, sized for the largest possible set.

Populate the lookup table by walking through the combinations doing `Lookup[combination[i]]=i-baseIdx[nItems]`

Answer (score 0):

Sample solution:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // The input
        var n = 5;
        var t = new[] { 2, 4, 5 };

        // Helping transformations
        ComputeDistances(t);
        CorrectDistances(t);

        // The algorithm
        var r = CalculateRank(t, n);

        Console.WriteLine("n = 5");
        Console.WriteLine("t = {2, 4, 5}");
        Console.WriteLine("r = {0}", r);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void ComputeDistances(int[] t)
    {
        var k = t.Length;
        while (--k >= 0)
            t[k] -= (k + 1);
    }

    static void CorrectDistances(int[] t)
    {
        var k = t.Length;
        while (--k > 0)
            t[k] -= t[k - 1];
    }

    static int CalculateRank(int[] t, int n)
    {
        int k = t.Length - 1, r = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < t.Length; i++)
        {
            if (t[i] == 0)
            {
                n--;
                k--;
                continue;
            }

            for (var j = 0; j < t[i]; j++)
            {
                n--;
                r += CalculateBinomialCoefficient(n, k);
            }

            n--;
            k--;
        }

        return r;
    }

    static int CalculateBinomialCoefficient(int n, int k)
    {
        int i, l = 1, m, x, y;

        if (n - k < k)
        {
            x = k;
            y = n - k;
        }
        else
        {
            x = n - k;
            y = k;
        }

        for (i = x + 1; i <= n; i++)
            l *= i;

        m = CalculateFactorial(y);

        return l/m;
    }

    static int CalculateFactorial(int n)
    {
        int i, w = 1;

        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            w *= i;

        return w;
    }
}
```

The idea behind the scenes is to associate a k-subset with an operation of drawing k-elements from the n-size set. It is a combination, so the overall count of possible items will be [(n k)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). It is a clue that we could seek the solution in [Pascal Triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle). After a while of comparing manually written examples with the appropriate numbers from the Pascal Triangle, we will find the pattern and hence the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I used user515430's answer and converted to python3. Also this supports non-continuous values so you could pass in [1,3,5,7,9] as your pool instead of range(1,11)

```
from itertools import combinations
from scipy.special import comb
from pandas import Index

debugcombinations = False

class IndexedCombination:
    def __init__(self, _setsize, _poolvalues):
        self.setsize = _setsize
        self.poolvals = Index(_poolvalues)
        self.poolsize = len(self.poolvals)
        self.totalcombinations = 1
        fast_k = min(self.setsize, self.poolsize - self.setsize)
        for i in range(1, fast_k + 1):
            self.totalcombinations = self.totalcombinations * (self.poolsize - fast_k + i) // i

        #fill the nCr cache
        self.choose_cache = {}
        n = self.poolsize
        k = self.setsize
        for i in range(k + 1):
            for j in range(n + 1):
                if n - j >= k - i:
                    self.choose_cache[n - j,k - i] = comb(n - j,k - i, exact=True)
        if debugcombinations:
            print('testnth = ' + str(self.testnth()))

    def get_nth_combination(self,index):
        n = self.poolsize
        r = self.setsize
        c = self.totalcombinations
        #if index < 0 or index >= c:
        #    raise IndexError
        result = []
        while r:
            c, n, r = c*r//n, n-1, r-1
            while index >= c:
                index -= c
                c, n = c*(n-r)//n, n-1
            result.append(self.poolvals[-1 - n])
        return tuple(result)

    def get_n_from_combination(self,someset):
        n = self.poolsize
        k = self.setsize
        index = 0
        j = 0
        for i in range(k):
            setidx = self.poolvals.get_loc(someset[i])
            for j in range(j + 1, setidx + 1):
                index += self.choose_cache[n - j, k - i - 1]
            j += 1
        return index

    #just used to test whether nth_combination from the internet actually works
    def testnth(self):
        n = 0
        _setsize = self.setsize
        mainset = self.poolvals
        for someset in combinations(mainset, _setsize):
            nthset = self.get_nth_combination(n)
            n2 = self.get_n_from_combination(nthset)
            if debugcombinations:
                print(str(n) + ': ' + str(someset) + ' vs ' + str(n2) + ': ' + str(nthset))
            if n != n2:
                return False
            for x in range(_setsize):
                if someset[x] != nthset[x]:
                    return False
            n += 1
        return True

setcombination = IndexedCombination(5, list(range(1,10+1)))
print( str(setcombination.get_n_from_combination([2,5,7,8,10])))
```

returns 188