# How to return all combinations that contains a given *partial* combination?

Tags: c#, permutation, combinations

I have this c# class that calculates *n choose k* and then generates all possible combination in lexicographical order. It can also return each combination's order number, e.g: passing [1,2,3,4,5] would return 1 given n choose k(30,5), and 142506 for [26,27,28,29,30].

Is there a way to return all order numbers containing a **partial** combination? So if I pass [1,2,3,4] it would return: 1,2,3,...25,26.

```
1: [1,2,3,4,5]
2: [1,2,3,4,6]
3: [1,2,3,4,7]
...
25: [1,2,3,4,29]
26: [1,2,3,4,30]
```

I need this for a lottery draw. I want each ticket to have it's combination's order number and I need to display the total of possible winners as each of the 5 balls are drawn. Right now each ticket has the actual combination and I run a query to get partial winners but I want to optimize this proccess.

Comment: Just generate permutations as usual, minus those included in the list, then prepend said list?

Comment: (+1) to question for fair point distribution ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a function that, for a combination [a, b, c, d, e], returns that combination's order number. Then you can get the combination set for (the set of possible numbers minus the numbers already picked) choose (the number of picks you have yet to make), add in the numbers already picked to each combination, reorder each combination, and use that function to get the order number.

EDIT: This might help: saliu.com/bbs/messages/348.html

EDIT2: And the answer is here: [How to calculate the index (lexicographical order) when the combination is given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307222/how-to-calculate-the-index-lexicographical-order-when-the-combination-is-given)

EDIT3: I took a stab at some C# code for this:

```
private IEnumerable<int[]> CombinationsFor(int n, int k);
private int CombinationsCount(int n, int k);

private int IndexFor(int n, int[] combination)
{
    int k = combination.Count();
    int ret = 0;

    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        for (j++; j < combination[i]; j++)
        {
            ret += CombinationsCount(n - j, k - i - 1);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

private IEnumerable<int> PossibleCombinations(int n, int k, int[] picked)
{
    int m = picked.Count();

    int[] reverseMapping = Enumerable.Range(0, n)
        .Where(i=>!picked.Contains(i))
        .ToArray();

    return CombinationsFor(n-m, k-m)
        .Select(c => c
            .Select(x=>reverseMapping[x])
            .Concat(picked)
            .OrderBy(x=>x)
            .ToArray()
        )
        .Select(c => IndexFor(n, c));
}
```

Comment: I already got the function to calculate the index for a given combination, but thanks for explaining the logic needed to get the results I need. Now I don't know which answer to accept, yours or saverio's. :)

Comment: reverseMapping ;)  Good C# implementation (+1). I thank god for not having to pay my bills coding in C# :D

Answer (score 3):

The combinations you need are `(n-d) choose (k-d)` where `d` is the number of fixed draws.

When you generate them they won't have the correct numbers (they are skipping the last `d` numbers instead of the ones you want) but just reword your combinations using the reverse order mapping of your sublist:

(in pseudo-python-code, as this isn't related to C# at all)

```
listing = [1, 2, ..., 30]
partial = [4, 7, 25]
draw_size = 5
remaining = listing - partial
reverse_order_mapping = [(index, item) in remaining.items_and_indexes]

n = listing.size  // 30
k = draw_size     // 5
d = partial.size  // 3

for comb in ((n-d) choose (k-d))
  actual_comb = comb.map(reverse_order_mapping)
  print actual_comb
end
```

Then you just call your function with the resulting combination(s) (after sorting it if needed).

Comment: Both your answer and Thom's have helped me understand what I need to get to the indexes, +1.