# Find the index of a given combination (of natural numbers) among those returned by `itertools` Python module

Tags: python, indexing, combinations, python-itertools

Given a combination of `k` of the first `n` natural numbers, for some reason I need to find the position of such combination among those returned by `itertools.combination(range(1,n),k)` (the reason is that this way I can use a `list` instead of a `dict` to access values associated to each combination, knowing the combination).

Since `itertools` yields its combinations in a regular pattern it is possible to do it (and I also found a neat algorithm), but I'm looking for an even faster/natural way which I might ignore.

By the way here is my solution:

```
def find_idx(comb,n):
    k=len(comb)
    idx=0
    last_c=0
    for c in comb:
        #idx+=sum(nck(n-2-x,k-1) for x in range(c-last_c-1)) # a little faster without nck caching
        idx+=nck(n-1,k)-nck(n-c+last_c,k) # more elegant (thanks to Ray), faster with nck caching
        n-=c-last_c
        k-=1
        last_c=c
    return idx
```

where `nck` returns the [binomial coefficient of n,k](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Evaluate_binomial_coefficients#Python).

For example:

```
comb=list(itertools.combinations(range(1,14),6))[654] #pick the 654th combination
find_idx(comb,14) # -> 654
```

And here is an equivalent but maybe less involved version (actually I derived the previous one from the following one). I considered the integers of the combination `c` as positions of 1s in a binary digit, I built a binary tree on parsing 0/1, and I found a regular pattern of index increments during parsing:

```
def find_idx(comb,n):
    k=len(comb)
    b=bin(sum(1<<(x-1) for x in comb))[2:]
    idx=0
    for s in b[::-1]:
        if s=='0':
            idx+=nck(n-2,k-1)
        else:
            k-=1
        n-=1
    return idx
```

Comment: +1 It might be helpful to take a look at the "source code" of `itertools.combinations`: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: These look like iterative versions of the [unchoose](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3143594/487339) ranker I keep in the toolbox.  `find_idx` seems faster than `unchoose`, which isn't surprising, as Python recursion tends to be slow.

Comment: Thinking out loud: would [combinatorial numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system) help here?

Comment: @Iarsmans Great link, thanks. Nevertheless I found a difference between lexicographic ordering explained in Wikipedia and the one used by itertools: the former assume decreasing ordering of chosen items, the latter increasing ordering. I'm trying to reduce my algorithm to something analogous (is not that far) to the elegant and fast one in Wikipedia, but I don't know whether it's feasible, due to such difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution seems quite fast. In `find_idx`, you have two for loop, the inner loop can be optimized using the formular:

```
C(n, k) + C(n-1, k) + ... + C(n-r, k) = C(n+1, k+1) - C(n-r, k+1)
```

so, you can replace `sum(nck(n-2-x,k-1) for x in range(c-last_c-1))` with `nck(n-1, k) - nck(n-c+last_c, k)`.

I don't know how you implement your `nck(n, k)` function, but it should be O(k) measured in time complexity. Here I provide my implementation:

```
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce # In python 3
def nck_safe(n, k):
    if k < 0 or n < k: return 0
    return reduce(mul, range(n, n-k, -1), 1) // reduce(mul, range(1, k+1), 1)
```

Finally, your solution become O(k^2) without recursion. It's quite fast since `k` wouldn't be too large.

### Update

I've noticed that `nck`'s parameters are `(n, k)`. Both n and k won't be too large. We may speed up the program by caching.

```
def nck(n, k, _cache={}):
    if (n, k) in _cache: return _cache[n, k]
    ....
    # before returning the result
    _cache[n, k] = result
    return result
```

In python3 this can be done by using `functools.lru_cache` decorator:

```
@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=500)
def nck(n, k):
    ...
```

Comment: Great "theoretical" improvement, I was looking exactly for such a formula. Unfortunately it seems not to bring much performance gain. I tried some tests and with great disappointment I found no speed advancement in comparison to the original version with `sum`. I guess that after all you need more cycles to calculate the 2 `nck` than to compute the several `nck` of the `sum` in the original version. By the way I updated the code to reflect your "theoretical" optimization.

Comment: Next optimization step should be to find a similar formula even for the main loop.

Comment: What a pity that the trick don't work well. I've introduced another way in my updated answer. The two method can be combined to use.

Comment: Caching surely is a possibility when the ranges of n and k are small (I actually used it in my real implementation), and in such case your improvement is useful cause it always needs just 2 lookups.

Answer (score 0):

I dug up some old (although it's been converted to Python 3 syntax) code that includes the function `combination_index` which does what you request:

```
def fact(n, _f=[1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720]):
    """Return n!
    The “hidden” list _f acts as a cache"""
    try:
        return _f[n]
    except IndexError:
        while len(_f) <= n:
            _f.append(_f[-1] * len(_f))
        return _f[n]

def indexed_combination(n: int, k: int, index: int) -> tuple:
    """Select the 'index'th combination of k over n
    Result is a tuple (i | i∈{0…n-1}) of length k

    Note that if index ≥ binomial_coefficient(n,k)
    then the result is almost always invalid"""

    result= []
    for item, n in enumerate(range(n, -1, -1)):
        pivot= fact(n-1)//fact(k-1)//fact(n-k)
        if index < pivot:
            result.append(item)
            k-= 1
            if k <= 0: break
        else:
            index-= pivot
    return tuple(result)

def combination_index(combination: tuple, n: int) -> int:
    """Return the index of combination (length == k)

    The combination argument should be a sorted sequence (i | i∈{0…n-1})"""

    k= len(combination)
    index= 0
    item_in_check= 0
    n-= 1 # to simplify subsequent calculations
    for offset, item in enumerate(combination, 1):
        while item_in_check < item:
            index+= fact(n-item_in_check)//fact(k-offset)//fact(n+offset-item_in_check-k)
            item_in_check+= 1
        item_in_check+= 1
    return index

def test():
    for n in range(1, 11):
        for k in range(1, n+1):
            max_index= fact(n)//fact(k)//fact(n-k)
            for i in range(max_index):
                comb= indexed_combination(n, k, i)
                i2= combination_index(comb, n)
                if i2 != i:
                    raise RuntimeError("mismatching n:%d k:%d i:%d≠%d" % (n, k, i, i2))
```

`indexed_combination` does the inverse operation.

PS I remember that I sometime attempted removing all those `fact` calls (by substituting appropriate incremental multiplications and divisions) but the code became much more complicated and wasn't actually faster. A speedup was achievable if I substituted a pre-calculated list of factorials for the `fact` function, but again the speed difference was negligible for my use cases, so I kept this version.

Comment: You can just use stdlib [`math.factorial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.factorial). And probably using [`math.comb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.comb) then you won't even need the factorial function (it looks like using `fact` just as a means to compute nCr, correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you need to better specify your task or I am just getting it wrong. For me it seems that when you iterating through the `itertools.combination` you can save indexes you need to an appropriate data structure. If you need all of them then I would go with the `dict` (one `dict` for all your needs):

```
combinationToIdx = {}
for (idx, comb) in enumerate(itertools.combinations(range(1,14),6)):
    combinationToIdx[comb] = idx

def findIdx(comb):
    return combinationToIdx[comb]
```

Comment: Using `dict` is more time and memory consuming than using `list`. Moreover, if you have (like I do) billions of combinations, to store all comb/index pairs you might need more memory and time than you have, whereas a function needs few bytes of memory and you spend time to get the index only when you need it.