# Python - Get index of a combination

Tags: python, loops

I need to generate combination from "a" to "]]]]]]" for example, in order to it I use this python script which works well.

```
import itertools

DATA_ALPHA_NUM = 
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789&-
()@=+;/!%$\\'\",.<>*^{}#~_[]"
b = 10

for i in range(1,int(b)+1):
   for e in itertools.combinations(DATA_ALPHA_NUM,i): print(''.join(e))
```

**But now I need to do the inverse, for exemple : if I give "1" to the new script it will output "a", if I give 90 it will ouput "]" etc.**

I wrote several scripts which worked fine for less than 737191 combinations but they were not good after.

**EDIT** : someone write something like that then delete it post It was almost perfect ..

```
alphaNumList = list(DATA_ALPHA_NUM)
alphaNumList.insert(0, "")

result = ["".join(item) for item in 
itertools.islice(itertools.product(alphaNumList, repeat=6), 0,1)]
```

Comment: if you have the memory, you could store the combinations in a dictionary by index. But that consumes a lot of memory, yes.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455634/find-the-index-of-a-given-combination-of-natural-numbers-among-those-returned

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I knew but I want to to it without loop I need to get the index very quickly ..

Comment: Someone write something like that "result = ["".join(item) for item in itertools.islice(itertools.product(alphaNumList, repeat=6), 0,1)]" was almost perfect but stop too soon

Comment: Yes but the idea was here

Comment: I know the guy. I fwded ypur question to him because he did smth similar

Comment: Thank you ! Hope he could help me again !

Comment: the answer came back, and now it works :) but in your question you're using `combinations`, you have to use `itertools.product(DATA_ALPHA_NUM,repeat=i):` for it to match.

Comment: La dernière réponse de votre ami ne m'a pas aidée au final. Car le problème survenait vers 8192 ou on revenait à "a" au lieu de aaa mais je l'ai fixé en faisant un set pour supprimer les doublons ! En tout cas merci beaucoup à vous deux !

Answer (score 1):

## Overview

The key to this is to walk through the cumulative combinations until the index is reached.

## Solution

```
from math import factorial

def comb(n, r):
    'Combinations of n things taken r at a time'
    return factorial(n) // (factorial(r) * factorial(n - r))

def nth_combination(population, r, index):
    'Equivalent to list(combinations(population, r))[index]'
    n = len(population)
    c = comb(n, r)
    if index < 0:
        index += c
    if index < 0 or index >= c:
        raise IndexError
    if r < 0 or r > n:
        raise ValueError
    result = []
    while r:
        c, n, r = c*r//n, n-1, r-1
        while index >= c:
            index -= c
            c, n = c*(n-r)//n, n-1
        result.append(population[-1-n])
    return tuple(result)
```

## Optimization

If speed is a concern, it is possible to to build faster version of the *comb()* function.

One way is to precompute the factorials and then look them up when needed:

```
fact = [1]
for i in range(1, 1000):
    fact.append(fact[-1] * i)

def comb(n, r):
    return fact[n] // (fact[r] * fact[n - r])
```

And there is another way that avoids large factorials altogether and doesn't require auxiliary storage:

```
def comb(n, r):
    c = 1
    r = min(r, n-r)
    for i in range(1, r+1):
        c = c * (n - r + i) // i
    return c
```

## How it works

Start by breaking the combinations into its component groups:

```
def groups(n, r):
    return [comb(n-i-1, r-1) for i in range(n-r+1)]

>>> comb(8, 3)
56
>>> groups(8, 3)
[21, 15, 10, 6, 3, 1]
```

This means that when you run `itertools.combinations('ABCDEFGH', 3)` for `n=8` letters taken `r=3` at a time, there are 56 combinations.  The first 21 start with `A`, the next 15 start with `B`, the next 10 start with `C`, the next 6 start with `D`, the next 3 start with `E`, and the last 1 starts with `F`.

Say you want to find the 25th combination out of the 56.  That falls in the second group, so your first letter is `B`.

And since 25 - 21 is 4, you'll then need to find the 4th combination in the 15 members of "B" group defined by `itertools.combinations('CDEFGH', 2)`.  Just repeat the above process until all the letters are extracted.

## Testing

Here's a test to make sure it gives the expected results:

```
from itertools import combinations

population = 'ABCDEFGH'
for r in range(len(population) + 1):
    for i, expected in enumerate(combinations(population, r)):
        actual = locate(list(population), r, i)
        assert expected == actual
```

Comment: Oh ok thanks I wrote something a bit like that before with factorial. I understand what do you mean I think

Comment: Work but it takes too long :/

Answer (score 1):

You don't want COMBINATIONS. Indeed, you want "aa". But with combinations, as you never pick TWICE same item, that won't happen.

So here a proper version with "cumulative product", indeed, as Raymond does with combinations, i have to count (90, 90 + 90 **2, 90 + 90 **2 + 90 **3, ...) to find which is the good power corresponding to the combination i'm tracking.

Notice that it's not optimized as i'm slicing over product... just to retrieve one value!

```
import itertools

alphaNumList = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789&-()@=+;/!%$\\'\",.<>*^{}#~_[]")

cumulative = [len(alphaNumList)]
for i in range(1, 10):
    cumulative.append(len(alphaNumList) ** (i+1) + cumulative[i - 1])


def getCombiFromIndex(combiNumber):
    p = 0
    while cumulative[p] < combiNumber:
        p += 1  # WARNING : not robust to combi greater than (10,90) in my case :)
    rest = combiNumber - 1 - (cumulative[p - 1] if p > 0 else 0)
    return "".join([item for item in itertools.islice(itertools.product(alphaNumList, repeat=p + 1), rest, rest + 1)][0])


print(getCombiFromIndex(1))  # "a"
print(getCombiFromIndex(90))  # "]"
print(getCombiFromIndex(91))  # "aa"
print(getCombiFromIndex(800064))  # "ah+1"
```

***UPDATE :*** I've added the method to retrieve list between 2 indexes, based on same concept but in this case, slice is better used :)

```
def getCombiListBetween(fromNumber, toNumber):
    combiList = []
    if fromNumber < toNumber:
        pF, pT = 0, 0
        while cumulative[pF] < fromNumber:
            pF += 1
        while cumulative[pT] < toNumber:
            pT += 1
        start = fromNumber - 1 - (cumulative[pF - 1] if pF > 0 else 0)
        end = toNumber - 1
        for p in range(pF, pT + 1):
            combiList += ["".join(item) for item in itertools.islice(itertools.product(alphaNumList, repeat=p + 1), start, min(cumulative[p], end) + 1)]
            start = 0
            end -= cumulative[p]
    else:
        combiList.append(getCombiFromIndex(fromNumber))
    return combiList

print(getCombiListBetween(8189, 8191)) # ['][', ']]', 'aaa']
```