# Recursive dealing of cards from deck?

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

A standard 52 card deck may be represented using integer values: {0,1,..,50,51}. A standard poker hand contains 5 values from this set, without repetition.

To represent all 52C5 unique hands from a deck, the following loop may be used:

```
    for (int card1 = 0; card1 < 48; card1++)
    {
        for (int card2 = card1 + 1; card2 < 49; card2++)
        {
            for (int card3 = card2 + 1; card3 < 50; card3++)
            {
                for (int card4 = card3 + 1; card4 < 51; card4++)
                {
                    for (int card5 = card4 + 1; card5 < 52; card5++)
                    {
                        var handAbcde = new List<int> { card1, card2, card3, card4, card5 };
                        // do something with the hand...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to know how to make this a recursive function. I attempted but I could not preserve the ordering of the cards from lowest to highest, as it would for the `for` loops above.

Example of desired output: (observe sequential ordering from lowest to highest without repetition)

```
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 5
0 1 2 3 6
.
.
.
47 48 49 50 49
47 48 49 50 50
47 48 49 50 51
```

Comment: Show us the recursive function that you have tried.

Comment: As well as the output.

Comment: Your desired output is not "sequential ordering from lowest to highest without repetition".

Comment: Google "combinations" and "lexicographical order". The best algorithm for generating successive combinations is NOT recursive, but straightforwardly tweaking the values in the array.

Comment: @Lee: that is a beneficial google search, thank you. I found many ideas presented in the results that would speed up the index hashing. I will try them out. In particular this one has several approaches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307222/how-to-calculate-the-index-lexicographical-order-when-the-combination-is-given

Answer (score 3):

Here's a helpful extension method, which does what you want using recursion:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPermutations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int count)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (count == 1) yield return new T[] { item };
        else foreach (var result in items.Skip(i + 1).GetPermutations(count - 1))
            yield return new T[] { item }.Concat(result);
        ++i;
    }
}
```

And here's a sample use, to generate all possible combinations of five cards from a 52-card deck:

```
foreach (var hand in Enumerable.Range(0, 52).GetPermutations(5))
{
    foreach (var card in hand)
        Console.Write(card + " ");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: +1 while this won't give the output the user is showing it does answer the question.

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks; Actually, the user's output is invalid for the question. He specifically says: "sequential ordering from lowest to highest without repetition" :D

Comment: I'm not sure why it is invalid. Can you explain?

Comment: The Linq solution above, I must admit is elegant. But it is slower than using For loops.

Comment: @sapbucket: I agree, it is much slower, but for me Linq is always worth the extra execution time, because it's easier to understand what it does. As to why your output is invalid: look at the third-to-last line. "47 48 49 50 49" is not sequential, and it is not without repetition.