# Retrieving a subset's lexicographic index

Tags: algorithm, combinations, time-complexity

I have a list of all subsets of size k from the set {1, 2, ... , n} ordered in a lexicographic order, e.g all subsets of size 2 from the set {1, 2, 3, 4} are {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}. where the index of {1, 2} is 0, {1, 3} is 1, and so on.

Now, I need to write an algorithm that receives a subset (assume the subset is ordered), and returns its index in the list.

I wrote the following algorithm:

```
int GetSubsetIndex(List<int> subset, int N)
{
    int Skip = 0;
    int Last = 0;
    int Depth = 1;
    int K = subset.Count;

    while (Depth <= K)
    {
        for (int i = Last + 1; i < subset[Depth - 1]; i++)
        {
            Skip += BinomialCoefficient(N - i, K - Depth);
        }

        Last = subset[Depth - 1];
        Depth++;
    }

    return Skip;
}
```

This algorithm uses the special structure of the lexicographic order of the subsets, here's the explanation:

Let's say we have a set of size 6 (N=6) and a subset of length 3 (K=3), then we have 6 choose 3 subsets. now, the number of subsets that start with 1 is 5 choose 2, the number of subsets that start with 2 is 4 choose 2, and so on...

If the first number in the subset is X, we can skip (N-1 choose K-1) + (N-2 choose K-1) + ... + (N-X choose K-1) subsets.
If X was the first number, the second number Y in the subset is at least X+1. Now we can skip (N-[X+1] choose K-2) + (N-[X+2] choose K-2) + ... + (N-Y choose K-2) and so on.

In the algorithm's code, Skip represents the number of subsets we skipped, last represents the last number we considered in the subset (initialized with 0 as the set starts with 1), Depth is how deep into the subset we are, and K is the length of all subsets.

The problem of this algorithm is that is runs with `O(N)` time if the binomial coefficient calculation is `O(1)` (if it was pre-processed) or `O(N*k)` (if it wasn't), in practice some subsets may be calculated very quickly. I am trying to figure a way of getting this index with a shorted time bound.

You can do any pre-processing you want as long as you don't use more than `O(N chooke K)` memory, which is the number of subsets.

Comment: Have you considered using binary search?

Comment: Yes, binary search gives a worse bound as each comparison takes O(K) time and the height of the tree is log2(N choose K) if it's well balanced.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307222/how-to-calculate-the-index-lexicographical-order-when-the-combination-is-given?rq=1), which has got some well explained answers. Not sure if you are going to do better than O(n), but would be interested if you can do

Answer (score 2):

The answer you want is the Combinatorial Number System. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system

You can find instructions to find the nth subset of size k, or for a subset of size k, find its index.