# Combinatorics: Closed formula for assigning an index to each combination of given size

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say I have the set {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} and look at combinations of size 3; there are C(5, 3) = 10 of them, e.g. {0,1,2}, {0,1,3}, {0, 1, 4}, {0,2,3} etc.

**Is there a closed formula to index each of these combinations, e.g. {0,1,2} --> 0, {0,1,3} --> 1 etc?**

In code, if I had:

```
int index(int i1, int i2, int i3){...}
```

Then index(0, 1, 2) would return 0, index(0,1,3) would return 1 etc.

My attempt at solving index(i, j, k) was returning

```
i * 5^2 + j * 5^1 + k * 5^0 - #(junk up to ijk)
```

where junk are non-combinations, e.g. is stuff like {001, 002, 003, 004} up to {ijk}.

Comment: What you're looking for are `Rank` and `Unrank` functions; just google "rank unrank combinatorics" and you'll find both formulae and code

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the index (lexicographical order) when the combination is given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307222/how-to-calculate-the-index-lexicographical-order-when-the-combination-is-given)