# Most efficient way of storing exact set membership?

Tags: algorithm, serialization, set, membership

I have `N` slots.  There are `M` slots occupied.

I want to be able to tell *exactly* whether each slot is occupied.  (No Bloom filter answers, please.)

What is the absolute most storage-space efficient way of storing this information for `M << N`?

- Guess 0: A bitmap of `N` bits.
- Guess 1: An array of the positions of the occupied slots.  Reasonably good for small `M`.
- Guess 2: `p0 + (M-1)p1 + (M-1)(M-2)p2 + ...` where pX is the position of an occupied slot, among the remaining unoccupied slots.  This is slightly more efficient than guess 1, as the choice of unoccupied slot narrows as slots are filled.

Guess 2 still has a lot of waste; it includes the order in which the slots were filled, which is information that is not required.

What method is more efficient than Guess 2?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thanks, I've updated the question to specify storage-space efficiency.

Comment: So you don't care *at all* about query time? You are content to use an O(M) linear search to answer a query? And you also don't care if the entire structure needs to be rebuilt (also O(M)) in the case of a modification?

Comment: It also helps to have relative values.  How large are the items in the slots?  What is the ratio N/M?  How large are the values N and M (slot indices)?  You've already rejected two straightforward solutions, each of which *could* be the most space-efficient (I think).

Comment: The fundamental question is: if `M` is small, what is the need for storage efficiency? Or is it that `M` is only relatively small but not really small.

Comment: @rici Yes, I want to move set data across extremely low bandwidth links (1200-9600 baud) but each end has a few GBs of RAM and an GHz CPU.  Also, because I'm curious about how to absolutely minimise the size.

Comment: @Prune I agree that Guess 2 is not bad, but I am just curious as to how to remove the unneeded ordering information.

Comment: chrisdew: Although @PeterdeRivaz's answer is optimal, it is computationally difficult. I added a slightly-less optimal compression algorithm which is computationally much simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If M and N are known, then one way of achieving the best compression is to store the [index of the combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307222/how-to-calculate-the-index-lexicographical-order-when-the-combination-is-given).

There are `t= N!/((N-M)!*M!)` ways of choosing the M slots to be filled, so you will always need at least `log2(t)` bits to represent this information.

Storing the index of the combination allows you to use exactly `ceil(log2(t))`bits.

Comment: Great and correct answer.  Curious to know if it scales, it looks like O(n^2) at first glance.

Comment: Quibble: The last sentence is only correct if N and M are fixed; otherwise, the compressed sequence needs to contain a representation of both N and M. Assuming N and M are large, that is very little overhead, but it is enough to invalidate the word "exactly".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is no other information about the distribution of the values (i.e., every possible sample of M values is equally probable) then the optimal compression technique is that [given by @PeterdeRivaz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47317655/1566221), which is to simply using the ordinal of the enumeration of the sample out of the set of possible samples.

However, that is not trivial to compute, since the enumeration requires arithmetic on very large numbers.

Instead, it is possible to use a variant on Golomb compression, with only a small impact on the compression ratio.

Assume the numbers in the sample are in order. We start by computing the successive differences. Because we will never have two equal numbers, the sequence of differences will never include a 0; to gain a tiny additional compression, we start with one more than the first element of the sample, rather than the first element itself -- which means that the sequence never contains a 0 -- and then subtract one from each value. We now select some convenient number of bits `k`, and encode each value δ in the sequence as follows:

1. While δ > 2<sup>k</sup>, send a `1` bit and subtract 2<sup>k</sup> from δ
2. Now δ can be written in *k* bits. Send a `0` followed by the *k*-bit value of δ

We can choose `k` as `⌊log2(N/M)⌋`, which means that `N < 2k+1M`. (Taking the ceiling would be another possibility.) Consequently, the number of `1` bits sent in all of the iterations of step 1 in the above algorithm is less than `2M` (because each `1` accounts for 2<sup>k</sup> of the cumulative sum of the series, which is less than N). Each step 2 sends exactly `k + 1` bits, and there are exactly `M` executions of step 2, one for each value in the sample. Thus, the total number of bits sent is somewhere between `M × (k + 1)` and `M × (k + 2)`. But since we know `k < log2(N/M) + 1`, the total size of the transmission is certainly less than `M log2 N - M log2 M + 3M)`. (We also have to send the parameters `k` and `M`, so there is a bit of overhead.)

Now, let's consider the optimal transmission size. There are `N choose M` possible samples, so the size of the enumeration index in bits will be `log2(N choose M)`. If N ≫ M, we can approximate `N choose M` as `NM/M!`, and then using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) we get:

```
log(N choose M) ≈ M log N − M log M + M
```

(That's actually a slight overestimate, but it is asymptotically correct.)

Thus, the difference between the compressed sequence and the information-theoretic limit is less than 2 bits per value. (In practice, it is generally around one bit per value, because step 1 executes far less than the maximum number of times.)

Comment: Thanks for a great answer, I will use this and I wish I could upvote it more.  I will leave Peter's answer as accepted, as he answered exactly what I asked.