# Quick way to compute n-th sequence of bits of size b with k bits set?

Tags: algorithm, bit, combinatorics, sequences, computation

I want to develop a way to be able to represent all combinations of *b* bits with *k* bits set (equal to 1). It needs to be a way that given an index, can get quickly the binary sequence related, and the other way around too. For instance, the tradicional approach which I thought would be to generate the numbers in order, like:
For b=4 and k=2:

0- 0011

1- 0101

2- 0110

3- 1001

4-1010

5-1100

If I am given the sequence '1010', I want to be able to quickly generate the number 4 as a response, and if I give the number 4, I want to be able to quickly generate the sequence '1010'. However I can't figure out a way to do these things without having to generate all the sequences that come before (or after).
It is not necessary to generate the sequences in that order, you could do 0-1001, 1-0110, 2-0011 and so on, but there has to be no repetition between 0 and the (combination of b choose k) - 1 and all sequences have to be represented.

How would you approach this? Is there a better algorithm than the one I'm using?

Comment: This is very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307222/how-to-calculate-the-index-lexicographical-order-when-the-combination-is-given

Comment: I can give you the intuition but I can't write/debug a working code solution right now. Suppose b=4, k=2, and index=4. You start by deducing if the first digit is 0 or 1. How many combinations have 0 as the first digit? Exactly (3 choose 2) = 3, so the last such combination has index 2. Since 4 > 2, you know that the first digit must be 1. You can now recurse -- the rest of the combination is the solution to (b=3, k=1, index=4-3=1).

Comment: You lost me at "It is not necessary to generate the sequences in that order". How do you define `n-th` if there isn't a defined order?

Comment: I know the generating algorithm, so it doesn't matter if i generate the binaries in order. It only matters that I'm able to recover a sequence given it's index by knowing what method i used to generate it. I said that just in case there is an easier way to solve my problem that doesn't involve generating the binaries in order

Comment: @jingx I think they mean: a solution is still acceptable if it doesn't use the (lexicographical) ordering as listed in the problem, as long as the ordering used is a valid ordering.

Comment: @pkpnd your advice is interesting but would require calculating a lot of combinations, and I'm planning to deal with big sequences of bits (in the hundreds and thousands) so I think that would require too much processing

Comment: @Eduard Computing binomial coefficients isn't too expensive, see https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Evaluate_binomial_coefficients#Java which runs in O(k) time. But also, if you have thousands of bits, how are you planning to store the index (which would be a gigantic number, assuming k isn't tiny)?

Comment: My idea is to represent the sequence by using the smallest binary sequence that can represent the index. In my example, the '1010' would be represented as '100' because it's index (4) can be represented by '100'. If I know the values of b and k, I can get the original sequence back.

Comment: So the encoding algorithm receives the original sequence and must determine quickly which index it belongs to, and turn that index into its binary form. The decoding algorithm receives that binary form of the index, and must determine which binary sequence of length b with k set bits it relates to

Answer (score 3):

**pkpnd**'s suggestion is on the right track, essentially process one digit at a time and if it's a `1`, count the number of options that exist below it via standard combinatorics.

`nCr()` can be replaced by a table precomputation requiring `O(n^2)` storage/time. There may be another property you can exploit to reduce the number of `nCr`'s you need to store by leveraging the [absorption property](https://mikespivey.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/absorption-identity/) along with the standard [recursive formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Recursive_formula).

Even with 1000's of bits, that table shouldn't be intractably large. Storing the answer also shouldn't be too bad, as 2^1000 is ~300 digits. If you meant *hundreds of thousands*, then that would be a different question. :)

```py
import math

def nCr(n,r):
    return math.factorial(n) //  math.factorial(r) //  math.factorial(n-r)

def get_index(value):
  b = len(value)
  k = sum(c == '1' for c in value)
  count = 0
  for digit in value:
    b -= 1
    if digit == '1':
      if b >= k:
        count += nCr(b, k)
      k -= 1
  return count

print(get_index('0011')) # 0
print(get_index('0101')) # 1
print(get_index('0110')) # 2
print(get_index('1001')) # 3
print(get_index('1010')) # 4
print(get_index('1100')) # 5
```

Nice question, btw.

Comment: Thanks, took me a while to figure out that k-=1 only happens if digit=='1' but it totally made sense after i got it. Am i right to assume that for an original sequence of size b, the complexity of this algorithm is O(b²), since it has a fraction of b calls to a function of complexity O(b)?

Comment: Yes that's correct, this algorithm is O(b^2). I looked into it, you can improve to O(b) by leveraging the [absorption identity](https://mikespivey.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/absorption-identity/). I'll leave that as an exercise. :)